I am setting up two services using PHP-FPM and NGINX, and whenever one accesses the other, the NGINX page always appears
I created a container with PHP-FPM to act as the backend and admin for another PHP container. The second container will serve as the "frontend," fetching information from the first container.
Both are similar and have almost the same NGINX configuration. The difference is that the service acting as the web frontend will have a "wildcard subdomain," allowing access to any subdomain that PHP will handle on the backend.
I can access both services individually through the browser without issues (e.g., http://imobil.localhost:8090 and http://ANY-SUBDOMAIN.web-imobil.localhost:8090). The problem arises when I try to access the API service from the web service—it always returns the NGINX HTML page:
Welcome to nginx!
If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.

I'm unsure if I'm doing this correctly, but based on my knowledge, when I create the PHP containers, a script runs to add a .conf file to the PHP container and another .conf file to the NGINX container.
I'll share the files here, but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
PHP contianer file (admin / API)
server {

    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    listen 80;

    server_name imobil.localhost;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/imobil/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

NGINX container file (admin/api)
server {

    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    listen 80;

    server_name imobil.localhost;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/access.log;

    root /var/www/html/imobil/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass ms-imobil:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}

PHP container file (frontend with wildcard subdomain)
server {

    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    listen 80;

    server_name web-imobil.localhost;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/web-imobil/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }

    # Subdomínio curinga
    location ~ ^/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\.web-imobil\.localhost {
        set $subdomain $1;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /$subdomain/$1 break;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

NGINX container file (frontend with wildcard subdomain)
server {

    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 300;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300;
    proxy_send_timeout 300;

    listen 80;

    #server_name web-imobil.localhost;
    server_name web-imobil.localhost *.web-imobil.localhost;

    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/access.log;

    root /var/www/html/web-imobil/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass ms-web-imobil:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}

The containers names are "ms-imobil" and "ms-web-imobil"

How are you accessing the API? Be as specific as possible

Acessing direct in browser from http://imobil.localhost:8090... i found the solution.. will write here.

I found the solution..
The problem is that I was seeing the nginx home page because the container inside the application was accessing the API and going to the /var/www/html folder and still had to go into the "imobil/public" folders, but that wasn't happening. The nginx file that the application was accessing was /var/www/html/index.nginx-debian.html .
So I understood that the problem was inside the ms-imobil container.
So I looked for the solution and found it in the default nginx file inside the application ( /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default ).
I changed it to access the application's default folder (/var/www/html/imobil/public) and configured it to access index.php and it worked!
